# changing dependentObservable() function, to enable chained writes

Tags: knockout.js

I've found out (thanks to the KO forum) that for computed observables, it's not possible to chain writes like this:
`viewModel.someComputed(20).otherComputed(100).someObservable('hi')`

and this bummed me because I have many observables which I want to `extend()` - and so they will become computed, and so I have to remove all the chained calls.

So I've made this small change in the dependantObservable() function (just added: return this;)

```js
function dependentObservable() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        set.apply(dependentObservable, arguments);
        return this;
    } else {
        return get();             
    }
}
```

And now I can chain writes!

My question is: **what's the downside of doing this?**
I assume there is one, because this wasn't implemented :P

Thanks,
Uri G

Comment: I don't think that this will cause any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be any issues. First, all code that was written before your change assumed that computed observables aren't chainable and thus no one would use the value returned by a setter. Second, all places where the return value is used are calling getter.

In other words all legacy code looks like

```
var value = obj.property(); // note the lack of parameters
obj.property(value); // note the absence of either chaining or assignment
```

Without chaining this code:

```
obj.property(value).anything
```

would throw a type error. So the only case to worry about is

```
someVar = obj.property(value);
```

which currently always returns `undefined`. And as for me it looks like a rather bogus code since there are much better ways to set some variable to `undefined`.

So if you want chainig go with this change.

> Any idea why it wasn't implemented?

Because in most traditional languages (Java, C#, C++, PHP) chaining is usually an exception rather than a norm. In JavaScript world only a few libraries use chaining heavily like jQuery, Underscore and d3. Most other libraries including Knockout don't rely on it, though.

Also Steve Sanderson could have just forgotten to put chaing support for computed observables. Send him a suggestion ;)

Comment: Thanks for the carefully thought out answer, we've reached the same conclusions :)